# Is there a way to combine the columns from two separate stacked bar graphs into one graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to make a single stacked bar graph that says how many studies (Y axis) were requested and completed for each project (X axis) by study category. Each project would have two stacked bars, one for requested studies, and one for completed studies.

Here is an example of what I use for data:

[image: data]

I can separate it into one set of data for requested studies and one set for completed, and I come up with this (ignore ludicrous colors and titles):

[image: stack]

And this is the code I use:

```
data<-read.csv("table56req.csv")
data
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=proj, y=req, fill=cat)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack") + 
  labs(title="Type of Study by Project", x="Project", y="Number of Studies") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=30,hjust = 0.5)) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white')) + 
  theme(axis.line = element_line(color="black", size = 0.5)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x= element_text(size=10,color = "black")) + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=12, color = "black")) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,20,5)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Bowersock","Dorena","Holtwood","Jackson","Milford","Nisqually","Smoky Mtn")) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size=12,vjust=-0.5,hjust=0.5)) + 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=12,vjust=2,hjust=.5)) + 
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Categories", labels = c("Biota and Biodiversity","Connectivity and Fragmentation","Geomorphology","Landcover","Water Quality","Water Quantity")) + 
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA),legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black"), legend.background = element_rect(linetype = "solid", colour = "black")) + 
  theme(legend.title.align=0.5)
```

Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Comment: Yes, a reprex of actual data is helpful, not so much an image of data.

Comment: Sorry duck, I will next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but you'll probably need to use facets. This isn't a huge problem, since facets are easy to hide.

Your question had an image of data rather than anything that could be copied and pasted, so I have made a simple reproducible example with a similar structure to your data frame:

```r
df <- data.frame(cat = factor(paste("cat ", rep(letters[1:5], each = 4))),
                 proj = factor(paste("proj", rep(LETTERS[1:4], 5))),
                 req = c(0, 10, 10, 11, 7, 11, 11, 1, 2, 3,
                         2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1),
                 comp = c(0, 12, 11, 15, 6, 15, 15, 1, 2, 3, 
                         2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1))
df
#>       cat   proj req comp
#> 1  cat  a proj A   0    0
#> 2  cat  a proj B  10   12
#> 3  cat  a proj C  10   11
#> 4  cat  a proj D  11   15
#> 5  cat  b proj A   7    6
#> 6  cat  b proj B  11   15
#> 7  cat  b proj C  11   15
#> 8  cat  b proj D   1    1
#> 9  cat  c proj A   2    2
#> 10 cat  c proj B   3    3
#> 11 cat  c proj C   2    2
#> 12 cat  c proj D   2    1
#> 13 cat  d proj A   1    1
#> 14 cat  d proj B   0    1
#> 15 cat  d proj C   0    0
#> 16 cat  d proj D   2    1
#> 17 cat  e proj A   0    2
#> 18 cat  e proj B   1    1
#> 19 cat  e proj C   2    2
#> 20 cat  e proj D   1    1
```

We need to reshape the data so that it is in long format (i.e. all the values are in one column, and there is a new column of factors specifying whether the value is `req` or `comp`). You can use `tidyr::pivot_longer` for this.

```r
pivot_longer(df, cols = c("req", "comp")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, value, fill = cat)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(~proj, switch = "x") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.5, 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() +
  labs(x = "Project") + 
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "points"),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: I think that if I went on this website and asked, how can I use R to discover the fountain of youth, within 10 minutes someone would have an answer. Allan, you have no idea how much this helps me. Thank you so much!!

Comment: one more question- is there a way to make the requested column come first?

Comment: @MatthewAldrovandi yes. Paste this line `mutate(name = factor(name, levels = c("req", "comp"))) %>%` between the `pivot_longer` line and the `ggplot` line

Comment: Aaaand @Allan Cameron saves the day again. Virtual beer to you.